# Trying to remap a name in SQL queries if a nickname is defined in another table

Tags: sql, select

Pardon the neophyte question, because I'm sure this is trivial.  How do I map a value from Table A to a value in Table B *if* it exists in Table B, but use the *original* value from Table A otherwise?

I have a table of donations and a table of donors, but over the years donors may change their names because of marriage or other reasons.  Donations will show up under both old and new names, but I would like to be able to use the new names when running multi-year reports, so I've created a table of nicknames.  (I would have called these aliases if that didn't have a defined meaning in SQL.)  In my actual scenario, I have certain attributes attached to the donor records, and I need to be able to look up those attributes in the current record even if I come across old names.

Table `donations`:

```
    Name           Amount
    Jane Doe       $20
    Bruce Johnson  $50
    Jane Brown     $20
```

`Jane Brown` is just `Jane Doe`'s new name, but she has also requested that statements to go to `Jane and Sam Brown`.  Note that `Bruce Johnson` has not changed his name, so he has no entry in the nicknames table.  My aliases table looks like this:

Table `nicknames`:

```
    Nickname      Name
    Jane Doe      Jane and Sam Brown
    Jane Brown    Jane and Sam Brown
```

I need to be able to work with the data as if it were:

```
    Name                Amount
    Jane and Sam Brown  $20
    Bruce Johnson       $50
    Jane and Sam Brown  $20
```

Because this kind of lookup will happen frequently, I'm looking for a simple way to incorporate it into more complex `select` statements.

I see a lot of questions and answers about simply determining whether a value is used in another table, but that only gets me half of the way to what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) statement. Example:

```
Select isnull(N.name, D.name)  as Name, amount
From donations D
left join nicknames N on N.nickName= D.name
```

if nick name is not null then nick name will be selected, otherwise it will select name

Comment: So clear once I mentally worked through it.  Thank you.  It turns out I had to use `ifnull()` on MySQL, but this answer was what I needed.

Comment: @NeilSteiner . . . You should use `COALESCE()`.  That is the standard function to do what you want.